# How to run a method after the site has been pinged?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet that needs to run a method after the site has been pinged.

```
My servlet:

  @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

   this.myMethod();
}
```

It needs to run `myMethod()` after the site has been pinged. How to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by the site pinged?  Is someone going to be calling an API endpoint?  Are they going to view a servlet page??

Comment: @SusanMustafa nothing like that. I have a server that sends ping request on the site, after that it needs to trigger the method. For example "ping 127.0. 0.1." where the ip is my sites ip.

Comment: What you have is a REST controller that gets invoked by requesting the registered resource URL with a Http POST. A low-level ping cannot do something like this.

Comment: How about @Inject on the servlet? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @WScoder 
ping is not http, so you'll never reach your java code!
what difference could @ Inject make???

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> after the site has been pinged.
>
> "ping 127.0. 0.1."

Incorrect, your web site is not being pinged. The host computer (OS) is being pinged.

The [*ping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) utility tool present in most operating systems makes a brief connection to your host computer, but not to your web server. So no Servlet will be invoked.

Therefore you cannot run code within your Servlet container in response to a `ping` connection.